# Assign variable to form field value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to assign a value to a hidden form field, the value comes from a query string parameter. The function to extract the query string parameter works fine, however the function to assign the variable (using document.forms) to the hidden form field value attribute doesn't seem to work, the value is empty if I inspect element, however it works if I run it through the console in Chrome. Many thanks.

Get variable from function that finds query string:

`var actionCode = getAllUrlParams().actioncode;`

Set hidden form field value:

```
function setHidden()
{
  document.forms[0].action.value += actionCode;
  return true;
}
```

Form HTML:

```
<input id="field25" name="action" type="text" value="" class="field-size-top-large" disabled="disabled">
```

Live page is here: http://exhibit.ubm-events.com/LP=83?cid=sm(n)_VIS_DRV20180515%7C1&actioncode=EMA1234

Comment: "action" is a reserved word, it is the form's action i.e. its target URL, so bad idea to give it as name of a form field. Change the name and your existing logic will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
function setHidden(a,b){
      return a*b;
 }


document.getElementById('field25').value = setHidden(2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the `actionCode` variable to the function so that it's definitely in scope, and use `.getElementById` seeing as the element *has* an ID.

```
function setHidden(actionCode)
{
  document.getElementById("field25").value += actionCode;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I think you does not need to pass actionCode into function because it is a global variable.

Comment: @SudhirOjha I think you're making an assumption seeing as the OP hasn't stated it's a global variable, just that they get the variable from another function. We can't see the rest of the code so we can't determine scope here.

Comment: yes i assuming that because the variable is declared at outside of function and no where given how he calling setHidden() to pass variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried adding the variable to function, still the same issue, the live page is here, its the Action code field: http://exhibit.ubm-events.com/LP=83?cid=sm(n)_VIS_DRV20180515%7C1&actioncode=EMA1234

Comment: @user2890068 I can't see anywhere in your code that you actually call `setHidden()` ? I see the function, but where do actually use it?

Comment: @MacroMan Thanks, I added to the body: onload="setHidden()", now it says undefined?

Comment: Doesn’t work quite like that - I’m just nipping out for a bit but will take a look when I’m back if you’ve not sussed it out by then.

Answer (score -1):

you need to select the element using jquery and assign the value to it

```
$("#field25").val("your value")
```

Ref http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Comment: Where has the OP stated they are using jQuery? Also this is no different from `document.getElementById()`